# finding the generators of a matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, modular-forms

I know the two generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are $S=\begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & -1  \\
    1& 0 
\end{bmatrix}$
and $T=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Furthermore,
$T^n =\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & n  \\
    0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Suppose I have any matrix $A$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. I want to find its generators. Here is what I have done so far:

I am trying to find the $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$A=S^a T^b S^{-c} T^{-d} \iff A T^d S^c= S^a T^b$.
Also, since $S^4=1$, I assumed  $1 \leq a,c \leq 4$.

In general, I tried to  compare the coefficients of $A$ for every possible values of $a$ and $c$, without success.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5):

Following Diamond's book [p](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf).21, the idea is to right multiply by $T^{-n}S$ to replace the bottom row $(c,d)$ by $(d-nc,-c),n = \lfloor d/c \rfloor$ ie. one iteration of the $\gcd$ algorithm, to reduce iteratively the bottom left coefficient $c$ until it is $0$.

Once this is done then $ad-bc = 1$ implies the matrix is $T^b$.

Thus the obtained decomposition is $A   = (-1)^jT^b\prod_{i=j}^1 (S T^{n_i})$

Comment: i dont understand your product going from i=j to 1. How do u choose j?

Comment: @usere5225321 we apply the [gcd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to $(c,d)$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this question I just wrote this https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.04804
Hope it helps, the formula is explicit.

Comment: Are you willing to summarize your results for us, here on this site? (As part of your newly posted answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1945361)